# quickest way to look up nearest index value

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy

consider the time series `s` and it's index `tidx`

```
tidx = pd.date_range('2010-12-31', periods=3, freq='M')
s = pd.Series([0, 31, 59], tidx)
```

If I wanted to use `s` as a lookup series and passed the date `'2011-02-23'`, I'd want to get the most recently available value.  In this case that would be `31`.

I've done

```
s.resample('D').ffill().loc['2011-02-23']

31
```

This does the job, but I had to resample the whole series just to get a single value.  What is a more appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) -

```
s[s.index.searchsorted('2011-02-23','right')-1]
```

Fun is when you beat yourself! So, here's a bit more of NumPy into the mix for further performance boost -

```
s[s.index.values.searchsorted(np.datetime64('2011-02-23'),'right')-1]
```

Runtime test -

```
In [235]: tidx = pd.date_range('2010-12-31', periods=300, freq='M')
     ...: s = pd.Series(range(300), tidx)
     ...: 

In [236]: s[s.index.searchsorted('2035-03-23','right')-1]
Out[236]: 290

In [237]: s[s.index.values.searchsorted(np.datetime64('2035-03-23'),'right')-1]
Out[237]: 290

In [238]: %timeit s[s.index.searchsorted('2035-03-23','right')-1]
10000 loops, best of 3: 63 µs per loop

In [239]: %timeit s[s.index.values.searchsorted(np.datetime64('2035-03-23'),'right')-1]
10000 loops, best of 3: 46.7 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

what about this?

```
In [150]: s[s.index <= '2011-02-23'].tail(1)
Out[150]:
2011-01-31    31
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

PS it'll work only if the index is sorted...

Answer (score 2):

I used `s.index.get_loc()`

[docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html)

It allows to find the "closest" index value location.

```
s.iloc[s.index.get_loc('2011-02-23', 'ffill')]
```